# Count number of elements in the html table

Tags: javascript, html-table

What approach should I use to count the number of elements in an  Html table?

For example: If I have a 3*3 table and I need to count number of A's and B's

```
                A  A  A
                B  A  B
                B  A  A
```

Comment: Could you please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: `$("#myTable td:contains('A')").length`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This javascript function will help you to retrive content of each cell and after getting the content you can write your own logic on that

```
<script>
 function GetCellValues() {
    var refTab = document.getElementById("YOUR_TABLE_ID")
    var  ttl;
     // Loop through all rows and columns of the table and popup alert with the value
    // /content of each cell.
      for ( var i = 0; row = refTab.rows[i]; i++ ) {
        row = refTab.rows[i];
        for ( var j = 0; col = row.cells[j]; j++ ) {
          alert(col.firstChild.nodeValue);
        }
      }
 }
</script>
```

And below code will fulfill your requirement

```
<script>
function getAandBCount() {
var refTab = document.getElementById("YOUR_TABLE_ID")
var  ttl;
var a=0;
var b=0;
for ( var i = 0; row = refTab.rows[i]; i++ ) {
   row = refTab.rows[i];
   for ( var j = 0; col = row.cells[j]; j++ ) {
       if(col.firstChild.nodeValue == 'A'){
        a++;
       }else if(col.firstChild.nodeValue == 'B'){
           b++;
        }
   }
}
alert(a);
alert(b);
}
</script>
```

Comment: imo too much code for such a simple task, but +1 for separating data and presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery

```
var counter = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table td').each(function(){
        if ($(this).text() === "A") counter++;
    });
    alert(counter + " 'A's found");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#mytable td:contains('A')").length;
```

Comment: hah, the same answer like in Artur's comment